# Flutter animated number, spinning

Tags: flutter, dart

How to create animation like from video, that must show specific number. Animation is like in casino.
[https://github.hubspot.com/odometer/docs/welcome/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rehqX.png) Like in second example where is 10, 000 is showed

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the design by using
[Number Slide Animation](https://pub.dev/packages/number_slide_animation)

**Add this to your package's pubspec.yaml file:**

```
number_slide_animation: ^0.1.1
```

**Install it with terminal with the command:**

```
flutter pub get
```

**Import:**

```
import 'package:number_slide_animation/number_slide_animation.dart';
```

**Sample Code:**

```
class Example extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Simple Example"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: NumberSlideAnimation(
            number: "12345678987654321",
            duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
            curve: Curves.bounceIn,
            textStyle: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: How Can I change number with animation by plus, minus with button click?

Comment: Check out the [counter app example](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-understanding-counter-app-ca89de564170).

Comment: This solution doesn't actually animate from one number to another, it just displays the first number with the animation. [This one does](https://pub.dev/packages/odometer).